# Enumeration from 1

Tags: python-2.7, enumerate

Is it possible to start counting number of iterations from 1 using enumerate function? If not, how to do it efficient way? There's particular piece of code I'm working with:

```
for nr, month in enumerate(range(1, 13)):
    print "Month: ", nr
```

I need to enumerate months from 1 to 12.

Comment: Did you think about reading [the manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)?

Comment: Yes, but I only took a look at looping techniques. Sorry, documentation sometimes looks like a mess to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply tell `enumerate()` where to start; it takes a second argument for that:

```
for nr, month in enumerate(range(1, 13), 1):
```

From the [`enumerate()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

> `enumerate(sequence, start=0)`
>   [...] The `next()` method of the iterator returned by `enumerate()` returns a tuple containing a count (**from *start* which defaults to 0**) and the values obtained from iterating over *sequence*

*Bold emphasis mine.*

Not that you really need it here, you are producing a range of numbers already, you can simply re-use `month` in this case as `nr` and `month` will always be equal now.